# how to return a value from js to html page in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create an autocomplete where it listview is crated dynamically from the data base for this i return the code in the js files from the listview is created filtered and then the selected list text is append to the input filed and the list is made hidden. I am apply the id to the listview who id issame as the id of the data in the table i amble to get the id of the selected list . what i want is to retrun the id of the select list to html page so that i can use it later to save it to the database I am using Jquery mobile autocomplete. here is the js code for autocomplete:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0","BPS CRM", 200000);
    function createlist(){


alert("i am in js ");
var usrname=new Array();
var usrid= new Array();
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('select * from users',[],function(tx,results){
            var dataset=results.rows;
            if(dataset.length>0){
            for(var i=0;i<dataset.length;i++){
                    usrname[i] =dataset.item(i).user_name;
                    usrid[i] = dataset.item(i).user_id;
                    console.log("Id from the database: "+usrid[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    if ( value && value.length > 1 ) {

                    for(var j=0;j<usrname.length;j++){
                    html +="<li id='"+usrid[j]+"'>"+usrname[j]+"</li>";
                }

         $ul.html( html );
         $ul.listview( "refresh" );
         $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");

         $.mobile.activePage.find('input[placeholder="Find a city..."]').attr('id','namesearch');
    }

    $("ul>li").click(function(){

        var textval=$(this).text();
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        alert("Id of selected user: "+id);
        $('#namesearch').val(textval);
        $.mobile.activePage.find("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');

    });
});}
```

here is the html script code:

```
$(function(){
createlist(); }



<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..."  data-filter-theme="d" >
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your logic looks fine, what's your problem?
And you lack a "}" in the end of the js file.

Comment: i want to get value of id in the html file can you tell me how to do that and i forget to paste "}" here.